# How to handle timeouts in poolboy?

Tags: erlang, elixir, actor, gen-server

I have a problem with a long-time consuming migration, which I desired to run in the parallel (it can be runned in the parallel). Actually migration is about taking all records in the database and implement time- and resource- consuming operations on each of them.

Sometimes individual record migration hanging out, so I give 10 minutes to finish. If migration isn't finished, I want it to gracefully shut down without any exception (see below)

I'm also using [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy) erlang package to parallelize implementation since migration consumes not only the time, but resources too. The problem is that I don't know how to handle error when timeout happened and code is going to break. My supervision tree is:

```
defmodule MyReelty.Repo.Migrations.MoveVideosFromVimeoToB2 do
  use Ecto.Migration

  alias MyReelty.Repo
  alias MyReelty.Repo.Migrations.MoveVideosFromVimeoToB2.Migrator

  # parallel nature of migration force us to disable transaction
  @disable_ddl_transaction true

  @migrator_waiting_time 10 * 60 * 1000 # timeout
  @poolboy_waiting_time @migrator_waiting_time + 10 * 1000 # give a time for graceful shutdown

  @pool_name :migrator
  @pool_size 3
  @pool_config [
    { :name, { :local, @pool_name }},
    { :worker_module, Migrator },
    { :size, @pool_size },
    { :max_overflow, 0 },
    { :strategy, :fifo }
  ]

  def up do
    children = [
      :poolboy.child_spec(@pool_name, @pool_config)
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyReelty.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)

    rows = Review |> Repo.all

    IO.puts "Total amount of reviews is: #{length(rows)}"

    parallel_migrations(rows)
  end

  def parallel_migrations(rows) do
    Enum.map(rows, fn(row) ->
      pooled_migration(@pool_name, row)
    end)
  end

  def pooled_migration(pool, x) do
    :poolboy.transaction(
      pool,
      (fn(pid) -> Migrator.move(pid, { x, @migrator_waiting_time }) end),
      @poolboy_waiting_time
    )
  end

  defmodule Migrator do
    alias MyReelty.Repo
    alias MyReelty.Review

    use GenServer

    def start_link(_) do
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, [])
    end

    def move(server, { params, waiting_time }) do
      GenServer.call(server, { :move, params }, waiting_time)
    end

    def handle_call({ :move, result }, _from, state) do
      big_time_and_resource_consuming_task_here    
      {:reply, %{}, state}
    end
  end
end
```

The problem if migration of some record in the database takes more than 10 mins I have this kind of exception:

```
20:18:16.917 [error] Task #PID<0.282.0> started from #PID<0.70.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.278.0>, {:move, [2, "/videos/164064419", "w 35th st Springfield United States Illinois 60020"]}, 60000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:604: GenServer.call/3
    (poolboy) src/poolboy.erl:76: :poolboy.transaction/3
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:94: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:45: Task.Supervised.reply/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<5.53617785/0 in MyReelty.Repo.Migrations.MoveVideosFromVimeoToB2.parallel_migrations/1>
    Args: []

20:18:16.918 [error] GenServer MyReelty.Repo terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.278.0>, {:move, [2, "/videos/164064419", "w 35th st Springfield United States Illinois 60020"]}, 60000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.70.0>, {:timeout, {GenServer, :call, [#PID<0.278.0>, {:move, [2, "/videos/164064419", "w 35th st Springfield United States Illinois 60020"]}, 60000]}}}
State: {:state, {:local, MyReelty.Repo}, :one_for_one, [{:child, #PID<0.231.0>, DBConnection.Poolboy, {:poolboy, :start_link, [[name: {:local, MyReelty.Repo.Pool}, strategy: :fifo, size: 1, max_overflow: 0, worker_module: DBConnection.Poolboy.Worker], {Postgrex.Protocol, [types: true, username: "adik", types: true, name: MyReelty.Repo.Pool, otp_app: :my_reelty, repo: MyReelty.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, database: "my_reelty_dev", hostname: "localhost", extensions: [{Geo.PostGIS.Extension, [library: Geo]}, {Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime, []}, {Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, [library: Poison]}], pool_size: 1, pool_timeout: 5000, timeout: 15000, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, database: "my_dev", hostname: "localhost", pool_size: 10, pool: DBConnection.Poolboy, port: 5432]}]}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [:poolboy]}], :undefined, 3, 5, [], 0, Ecto.Repo.Supervisor, {MyReelty.Repo, :my_reelty, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, [otp_app: :my_reelty, repo: MyReelty.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, database: "my_reelty_dev", hostname: "localhost", extensions: [{Geo.PostGIS.Extension, [library: Geo]}], pool_size: 1]}}
```

I tried to insert `terminate/2` or `handle_info/2` to `Migrator` and play with it, but I even haven't reached this functions to be invoked. How can I handle timeouts and prevent them to break my migration?

**UPDATED**

I used @johlo's hint, but I still getting time out. My function is:

```
def init(_) do
 Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
 {:ok, %{}}
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the `Migrator.move/2` (i.e. the `GenServer.call`) function times out it will crash the entire `MoveVideosFromVimeoToB2` process since that's the actual process that makes the `GenServer` call.

The solution here is to catch the timeout in the anonymous function in `pooled_migration`, something like (I'm not very familiar with Elixir syntax, so it might not compile, but you should get the idea) :

```
def pooled_migration(pool, x) do
:poolboy.transaction(
  pool,
  (fn(pid) ->
      try do 
          Migrator.move(pid, { x, @migrator_waiting_time })
      catch
          :exit, reason ->
             # Ignore error, log it or something else
             :ok
      end
   end),
  @poolboy_waiting_time
)
end
```

It's not the `Migrator` process that times out, it's the `GenServer` call to the `Migrator` that does and we need to `try-catch` that.

Also note that the `Migrator` process isn't killed it is still running, see the `timeouts` section in the [GenServer call documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#call/3).

UPDATE:
As @asiniy mentions in the comments the `@poolboy_waiting_time` should be set to `:infinity` so the `poolboy.transaction` function doesn't throw a timeout error when waiting for a free `Migrator` worker process. Since the `Migrator` will exit eventually this is safe.

Comment: It tends to be working! By the way, how can I kill `Migrator` process here?

Comment: When catching the `:exit` you can use [Process.exit/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#exit/2) to send a `:kill` signal to the `Migrator`. Or you can send it an ordinary `GenServer` message telling it to stop, but that will only be processed when it is done with the previous `move` task.

Comment: Give me a couple of days to test it and assign a bounty, okay?

Comment: Please add "remove timeout from poolboy since timeouts are handled in Migrator class" and I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: @asiniy If you remove it poolboy would only wait for 5 seconds for a free worker process, then exit out. In this scenario you would rather want to set the timeout to `:infinity` since you know the Migrator process will eventually finish?

Comment: @asiniy ok! I thought you meant to remove the timeout parameter from the `poolboy.transaction` call. I have updated the answer with this suggestion. Thanks for the bounty :)